# R extract raster and histogram for different spatialpolygon attributes

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sp

I'd like to create histograms of raster values for polygons based on different combinations of their attributes. Reproducible data below:

```
library(raster)
library(sp)   
poly <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
poly[] <- runif(ncell(poly)) * 10
poly <- rasterToPolygons(poly, fun=function(x){x > 9})
r <- raster(nrow=100, ncol=100)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r))
poly@data$place<-sample(letters[1:3], length(poly), TRUE)
poly@data$rank<-sample.int(3, length(poly), replace = TRUE)
plot(r)
plot(poly, add=TRUE, lwd=4) 
v <- raster::extract(r, poly, df=TRUE)
```

I can plot a histogram for all of the IDs (i.e., polygons) in `v` with `ggplot`

```
ggplot(v, aes(layer)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(count / sum(count))), binwidth = 0.25)
```

[image]

However, I'd like to create a set of three histograms based on the `rank` attribute (i.e., 1,2,3) and another set of three histograms based on the `place` attribute (i.e., a,b,c). Perhaps using `facet` in ggplot but I'm not sure how to link the IDs in `v` to the attributes in `poly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example:

```
library(raster)
#Loading required package: sp
pr <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
set.seed(1)
values(pr) <- runif(ncell(pr)) * 10
poly <- rasterToPolygons(pr, fun=function(x){x > 9})
poly$place <- sample(letters[1:3], length(poly), TRUE)
poly$rank <- sample.int(3, length(poly), replace = TRUE)

r <- raster(nrow=100, ncol=100)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
v <- raster::extract(r, poly, df=TRUE)
```

Assign an explicit ID the polygons, only keep variables of interest, and extract the data.frame from the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

```
poly$ID <- 1:length(poly)
poly$layer <- NULL
d <- data.frame(poly)
```

Merge

```
vd <- merge(d, v, by="ID")
```

Select a subset and make a histogram

```
x <- vd[vd$place == "a",]
hist(x$layer)
```